# Mysql IO write too much

Tags: mysql, io

I have a table that uses myisam engine on my server. There are 10 update statements per second on average. I found that the mysql process disk write a lot higher than the theoretical value. After experimenting, I suspect that modifying any column of data would rewrite the entire row of data. The following is an experiment...

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_update` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `str1` blob,
  `str2` blob,
  `str3` blob,
  `update_time` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `update_time` (`update_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I inserted 100000 rows data,each row has 30k string(10k per blob).After that I randomly update ‘update_time’ column 1 row/sec

```
while 1:
    sql = "update test_update set update_time=%d where id=%d" %(now, randomid)
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()

    slp_t = 1-(time.time()-end)
    if slp_t>0:
        time.sleep(slp_t)
    end=time.time()
```

and iotop shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJa8y.png

It seems like modifying an int column would rewrite the entire row(even more). Is that true? If the answer is yes, why was it designed like this? what should i do to avoid this waste?

Comment: Well, the question is - why are you using `MyISAM` in the first place? Let's start with that...

Comment: I can endure some data loss. Also don't need the transaction characteristics. I didn't realize that there was a problem with writing. My table records the user's data, there are many columns, each column with a string to save information (similar to json), the current problem is that I update a column data, will rewrite the entire row data lead to io become high. Is there any suggestion to optimize this situation?

Comment: Your arguments are not correct. InnoDB is vastly superior to MyISAM, it's not just transactions that it supports. As far as I know, from reading the source, MySQL avoids writing if record hasn't changed at all. Granted, I've no idea if this means if entire row gets re-written if only a single column changes or not, and I *think* this does depend on engine implementation. However, reconsider your decision about storage engine. MyISAM was excellent for day and age that it was made in, it's obsolete now.